# Отправить POST запрос из тильды в binom

Tags: javascript

прошу помощи по вопросу скриптов Тильда
Я уже подключил код, и он срабатывает когда я кликаю в форме на кнопку 'заказать'

```
<script>

    const btn = document.getElementById('rec492343854');
    btn.addEventListener('click',sendPost)
    function sendPost() {
        if (event.target.localName === "button"){
            console.log('s')
            
   
  }
  }
        
    
       
</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же в ексель у меня уже прилетает utm ссылка, так как у меня настроен clickID в binom

Вопрос, мне нужно получить в скрипте информацию по заказу в том числе utm, и отправить post запросом в binom, буду очень благодарен любой информации, спасибо

Comment: уже дошел к ответу сам, может будет полезно кому, как передавать клик в біном с тильды

Answer (score 0):

уже дошел к ответу сам, может будет полезно кому, как передавать клик в binom с тильды – лайкните ответ, если кому помогло )

```
if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
    linkData();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', linkData);
  }

  function linkData() {
    
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    let arr = links[3].baseURI.split('=');
    console.log(arr[1])
        
       //arr[1] - это ютм метка в сылке юзера
  fetch(`ссылка/click.php?cnv_id=${arr[1]}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  mode:'no-cors', //отключаю защиту CORS
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify()
}).then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));

    
  }
   
  }
  }
```